# What is the most efficent way to search a string for special characters and replace them?

Tags: java, regex, string

Im trying to search all the special characters in a string and escape them. The Input String must be failsafe so I need to escape the characters. 
The example String looks for example like this : `"Foo Bar "Gone Wild "- <br>Ted Talk</br> "`
To secure that the String still looks the same it needs to be something like this afterwards `"Foo Bar \"Gone Wild \" \- \<br\>Ted Talk \<\/br\>"`

I came up with this solution:

```
 final String[] metaCharacters = {"\\", "^", "$", "{", "}", "[", "]", "(", ")", ".", "*", "+", "?", "|", "<", ">", "-", "&", "#"};
    String outputString = "";
    for (int characterIndex = 0; characterIndex < metaCharacters.length; characterIndex++) {
        if (inputString.contains(metaCharacters[characterIndex])) {
            outputString = inputString.replace(metaCharacters[characterIndex], "\\" + metaCharacters[characterIndex]);
        }
    }
```

But I'm not very happy with that. Its written in Java.

Comment: @Wiktor that's assuming this is escaping them for regex. I mean, sure, it might be, but characters like `<>&#` don't have to be escaped for regex.

Comment: @AndyTurner: Sure, no need to.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ...but OP *is* looking to escape those characters.

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes, because OP does not know of a simpler approach

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but `Pattern.quote` won't give the desired output: `Pattern.quote("<>&#")` is `<>&#`; OP requires `\<\>\&\#`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Why would anyone need to escape them for use in a regex pattern? None is a special metacharacter.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew because... it's not escaping them for a regex pattern!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Im not escaping them for a regex.